# YII2 выводит закоментированный код на странице.Как исправить?

Tags: yii2, комментарии

```
<?/*= Breadcrumbs::widget([
    'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
]) */ ?>
```

На главной странице написано так:

```
isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [];
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, оформляйте код правильно, не нужно тулить непонятные картинки.

Answer (score 0):

Yii2 не причем. У Вас в настройках PHP запрещены короткие теги.

```
<? /* код */ ?>
```

Это настройка по-умолчанию, при ней короткие теги можно использовать только для вывода через '=', который закомментирован;

```
<?= $value ?>
```

Для включения нужно установить директиву:

```
short_open_tag=On
```

Правильным считается не использовать короткие теги без '=' вообще. Нужно закомментировать код? Допишите тэг до полного.